# Could you please suggest free jam app private sessions and lowest latency?

Tags: music

In our company we decided to share talents coworkers have. We were thinking about having some online jam. However, zoom has big latency, so it is not good for online jam.
I am looking for free jam application with private sessions and lowest latency.

I have seen so far several options:

`Jamulus`. I have connected to it, looks like it works like a radio and we can join any server. Is this possible to setup private server there?

`farplay`. Haven't tried it yet, but looks like it may satisfy my need. Looks like it is possible to setup a private session, but does it have any limitation? What if we have 10+ people willing to join? Will it accomodate it?

`ninjam`. What is this? Is this just some plugin or standalone application? Would it fit my requirements?

Others?.. Which one to chose, which one would satisfy our needs?